# Image Grayscale CSS Effect

Tags: html, css

I want to reduce the `brightness` of my image with CSS.

I'm using Mozilla Firefox and this is my code:

```
-moz-filter: brightness(0.5);
filter: brightness(0.5);
```

Why is it not taking effect?

Comment: Are these styles tied to an `img{...}` CSS declaration? or are they applied via an id/class selector?

Comment: If you want to use a greyscale effect, why not use the [`greyscale()` filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#grayscale()_2)?

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(100%);
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(50%);
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

It's all you need! I checked in Firefox and Chrome, code is working
[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/zy7cvqy9/)

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-filter: brightness(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-filter: brightness(50%);
    filter: grayscale(50%);
}
```